# Detecting click on image with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery script which tries to check if the user has clicked on an image with a certain class. The image in question appears like this:

```
<img src='media/voteup.png' class='upvote selected' />
```

My script tries to bind to a click on this image with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".upvote").click(function(){
        console.log("clicked");
        if ($(this).hasClass("selected")){
            // does stuff
        } else{
            // does stuff
        }
    });
});
```

However, I'm getting no console message. I've tried binding with:

```
$(".upvote").on("click", ".upvote", function(){...});
```

But it hasn't worked. I was wondering if I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

It turns out that the source of the problem was that I really stupidly tried to link in the js file with href instead of src. Ugh I need more sleep :P

Comment: Your code works fine on this fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/ppLocuac/ , are you getting any errors on the console ?

Comment: What's the surrounding html? Also, do you have any other event handlers that could be canceling event propagation? Try reproducing this issue on jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, it turns out that the source of the problem was that I really stupidly tried to link in the js file with href instead of src. Whoops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the event delegation `on()`, e.g :

```
$("body").on("click", ".upvote", function(){
    console.log("clicked");

    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")){
          // does stuff
    } else{
          // does stuff
    }
});
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".upvote").click(function(){
    alert("clicked");
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")){
      // does stuff
    } else{
      // does stuff
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src='media/voteup.png' class='upvote selected' />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var e; 
e=$(".upvote");
e.click=function()

{
    console.log("clicked");
    if (e.ClassName=="selected"){
      // does stuff
    } else{
      // does stuff
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("document").on("click", ".upvote", function(){...});
```

Comment: `document` will also work but listen to `body` is more efficient.